# ElasticSearch (2.2) Java filter between startDate and endDate if exists

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I want to have following filter with elasticsearch (java client):

If startDate exists and lower then now

If endDate exists and greater then now

I already have following but it doesn't show the once which have no startDate or endDate:

```
       //Start date end date

        BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("startDate").lte("now"));
        queryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("startDate"));
        queryBuilder.filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("endDate").gte("now"));
        queryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("endDate"));

        boolQueryBuilder.filter(queryBuilder);
```

The query in mysql looked like this:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_job WHERE (start_date <= CURDATE() OR start_date IS NULL) AND (end_date>=CURDATE() OR end_date IS NULL);
```

So how to do that?

---

I tried following from the answers but it still does not show the ones who have no startDate or endDate:

```
BoolQueryBuilder startDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
                .should(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("startDate"))
                .should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("startDate").lte("now"))
                .minimumNumberShouldMatch(1);
        BoolQueryBuilder endDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
                .should(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("endDate"))
                .should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("endDate").gte("now"))
                .minimumNumberShouldMatch(1);

        boolQueryBuilder.filter(startDateQuery).filter(endDateQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a query like this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder startDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
   .should(QueryBuilders.missingQuery("startDate"))
   .should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("startDate").lte("now"))
   .minimumShouldMatch(1);
BoolQueryBuilder endDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
   .should(QueryBuilders.missingQuery("endDate"))
   .should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("endDate").gte("now"))
   .minimumShouldMatch(1);
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder()
   .filter(startDateQuery)
   .filter(endDateQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) It looked promising but it still does not show the ones who have no date - see edit :)

Comment: Doh, you need to replace `existsQuery` with `missingQuery`, my bad

Comment: Impressive :) It works -> please correct your answer and I'll accept! Thanks a lot!!!