# Elasticsearch-problem in using java high level rest client rangeQuery()

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am using High level java rest client(6.5) and I need to filter datas according to some date range - 
let, I have these 4 documents (added a postman image) in a same index and in 2 documents I don't have publish_date and publish_end_date field so when I will put a range I need the documents which will come in between those range and the documents which don't have those range fields also.

My requirements are matching with this question

[ElasticSearch (2.2) Java filter between startDate and endDate if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899072/elasticsearch-2-2-java-filter-between-startdate-and-enddate-if-exists)

But the QueryBuilders.missingQuery is showing undefined for QueryBuilders in 6.5.

[image: The json documents]

Is that possible?

I have modified the query like below-

when I am using **only the range query** like below its working fine-

```
    BoolQueryBuilder startDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
               .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_date").lte("now"));
    BoolQueryBuilder endDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
              .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_end_date").gte("now"));
```

When I am using **only the mustNot query** like below I am getting the desired results-

```
    BoolQueryBuilder startDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
               .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_date"));
    BoolQueryBuilder endDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
              .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_end_date"));
```

But the problem is when I **mix both the queries** like below I am not getting any result(getting empty array)-

```
    BoolQueryBuilder startDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
               .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_date").lte("now"))
               .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_date"));
    BoolQueryBuilder endDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
              .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_end_date").gte("now"))
              .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_end_date"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing query is used in Elasticsearch 1 and 2. In Elasticsearch 5 it is deprecated.

Please see [deprecated reference here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-missing-query.html)

In QueryBuilders there is also an option called exist query so we can use that to search documents for which specific fields don't exist with must not boolean query.
Here we have to add must not with exist query to search those field non-exist docs along with range matched docs

```
setRangeFieldsQuery
     .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
     .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("field_name")));
```

Please refer [eixst query documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html#_literal_missing_literal_query) here

Comment: I have tried that one but its not working,I am not getting anything, the results which I was getting at the beginning with only the range query.

Comment: @JAVA Coder Can you add the full query you have used. **Should** is similar to **OR** condition in SQL have you passed the Range Query and Must Not Exist Query in Should then It should get all the result.

Comment: My requirement is-let, I have a content which have a publish_date(start) and publish_end date(end) and some contents doesn't have any date.so when someone search the documents he should see the contents 1> which don't have any publish_date and publish_end date  and 2>the documents with current_date>publish_date 3>current_date < publish_end date.I have written the below query -

Comment: BoolQueryBuilder startDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
       .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_date"))
       .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_date").gte("2019-05-26T05:48:27Z").lte(null));
    BoolQueryBuilder endDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
       .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_end_date"))
       .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_end_date").gte(null).lte("2019-07-26T05:48:27Z"));   and Executed this like-BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(startDateQuery).should(endDateQuery);

Comment: BoolQueryBuilder wholeBoolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
wholeBoolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_date").gte("2019-05-26T05:48:27Z"));
wholeBoolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_end_date").lte("2019-07-26T05:48:27Z"));
BoolQueryBuilder publishAndEndDateMustNot = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
publishAndEndDateMustNot.must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_date")));
publishAndEndDateMustNot.must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_end_date")));
wholeBoolQuery.should(publishAndEndDateMustNot);

Comment: Try this query and let me know
This should work like **(publish_date >= 2019-05-26T05:48:27Z || publish_end_date <= 2019-07-26T05:48:27Z || (Both publish_date && publish_end_date) don't exist)**

Comment: could you please tell me how to make this query using java rest client and how to execute?

Comment: I use io.searchbox/Jest for DB interactions

`SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(wholeBoolQuery);
Search search = (Search) new Search.Builder(searchSourceBuilder.toString()).addIndex(index).addType(type).build();
SearchResult result = client.execute(search);`

Comment: I just saw the High-level java rest client for search please refer [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search.html)

Sample Code:
`SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
searchRequest.indices("posts");
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);`

Comment: I know these things as I am using it I asked that how to make that particular query (which is my requirement) and how to execute that either with must,should or filter

Comment: Sorry, I might not be getting your question correctly. But, to my understanding your asking how the should,must_not and must is applied to the given query.

Comment: 1st Condition: publish_date >= 2019-05-26T05:48:27Z
1st Query: QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_date").gte("2019-05-26T05:48:27Z")
2nd Condition: publish_end_date <= 2019-07-26T05:48:27Z 
2nd Query: QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_end_date").lte("2019-07-26T05:48:27Z")
3rd Condition: If Both publish_date and publish_end_date must not exist
3rd Query: publishAndEndDateMustNot.must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_date"))); publishAndEndDateMustNot.must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_end_date")));

Comment: Must = AND Condition here saying that match docs that dont't have both the fields
Added all the 3 condtions query in Should = OR.Because Any condition in three matches then get that docs.

Comment: I have eddied my question please check it.

Comment: Sorry, Not able to find a better solution than the query added by me in the above comments