# Elasticsearch - must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery) and mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery) not working at a time

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-6

I am using High level java rest client(6.5) and I need to filter datas according to some date range- let, I have these 4 documents (added a postman image) in a same index and in 2 documents I don't have publish_date and publish_end_date field so when I will put a range I need the documents which will come in between those range and the documents which don't have those range fields also.

[Json Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPsRP.png)

I got some help from this question-
[ElasticSearch (2.2) Java filter between startDate and endDate if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899072/elasticsearch-2-2-java-filter-between-startdate-and-enddate-if-exists) as the **QueryBuilders.missingQuery** is deprecated so I am using **mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery)** by taking the reference from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-missing-query.html) but it is not working and I am not getting the results.

when I am using only the range query like below its working fine-

```java
BoolQueryBuilder startDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
           .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_date").lte("now"));
BoolQueryBuilder endDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
          .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_end_date").gte("now"));
```

[image: result 1]

When I am using only the mustNot query like below I am getting the desired results-

```java
BoolQueryBuilder startDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
           .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_date"));
BoolQueryBuilder endDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
          .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_end_date"));
```

[image: result 2]

But the problem is when I combine both the queries like below I am not getting any result(getting an empty array)-

```java
BoolQueryBuilder startDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
           .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_date").lte("now"))
           .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_date"));
BoolQueryBuilder endDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
          .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_end_date").gte("now"))
          .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_end_date"));
```

[image: result 3]

I want all the **result 1** and **result 2** values in **result 3**(thats my requirement).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what you should do:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
  .should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_date").lte("now"))
  .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_date")));
```

Answer (score 2):

Something's going wrong with your query and that's why you get no results.

```
BoolQueryBuilder startDateQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder()
           .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_date").lte("now"))
           .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_date"));
```

This means that the application will search in the repository to find results that do not contain "publish_date", but at the same time the "publish_date" to be lte("now"). Similarly, there is the same problem for the other query.

The queries you have used for results1 and results2 cannot be combined.

The set for this query is null and that's why you get no results!

**EDIT:**
You should use the "should" which means "OR" in elasticsearch.

```
BoolQueryBuilder startDateQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
  .should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_date").lte("now"))
  .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish_date")));
```

Similarly for the endDateQuery:

```
BoolQueryBuilder endDateQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
  .should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("publish_end_date").gte("now"))
  .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("publish__end_date")));
```

Comment: Then how can I get combination or as per my requirement how to make query could you please help?

Comment: you could use the "should" which is something like the "or" function. See @dadoonet answer and my edit!